# Average Students Of a school

Tags: r, tidyverse

[image]

Me and another student want to get the result per course average before they hit a 5,5.
We want to have an overview  that expresses for each course the average number of attempts a student has to take to get to a sufficient (result >= 5.5)

We know that we have to calcultate te total rows of result and groups that on the row course. an devine that.

But when we try that with a summarise we dont know how to group and calculate the rows and devine it.

```
df  %>% 
summarise(waarde = course/studnr )
```

Comment: Hello please post your data with `dput(mydata)` and not just with a screenshot. Also please include your desired output.

Comment: I know that A would be 1,25 and I'm gonna change the data in data column

Answer (score 3):

First you would need to calculate the number of attempts per student and per course. Afterwards, grouping by course alone allows you to calculate the average of attempts per course.

Would this help you out?

```
data <- data.frame(
  studnr = c(101, 101,101, 102, 102), 
  course = c("A", "A", "B", "A" , "B"), 
  result = c(3.7, 4, 7, 5.6, 7)
)

data %>% 
  group_by(studnr, course) %>% 
  summarise(nbAttempts = length(result < 5.5)) %>% 
  group_by(course) %>% 
  summarise(mean(nbAttempts))
```

Comment: On second evaluation, this might not lead to the right answer since length() always returns the same number, no matter the filter (results < 5.5). `sum(result <5.5)` would be better, but then B for 101 would have 0 attempts..

Assuming that a student only retakes an exam if his/her result is below 5.5, a simple count would do here. `nbAttempts = n()`